# Azure DocumentDB Single Account billed for multiple collections?

Tags: azure, billing, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure account. I created a single DocumentDB that I am using for a single web application.

My account just got disabled because I went over my spending limit.

I looked at the usage and it shows that I was billed for 3449 hours in the last 15 days. Well, since there are only 24 hours in a day I was confused.

When I sent a support request they said that my document db account is being billed for 11 different projects.

So what is a project? I never set up more than one DocDB instance and I have only been using it for a single web project. I only ever use the keys that were generated when I created the DocDB instance and I have never regenerated them.

Can anyone tell me what is going on? Why is my single "project" billing for 11 different "projects"? What is a "project" in this case and how do I fix it?

Comment: I have no idea what the notion of a _project_ is, regarding DocumentDB's model, but... how many _collections_ do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The billing is based on a per-collection basis in a DocumentDB account.

Also, a database account that contains no database or collection incurs a cost (equivalent to S1). Delete the database account to avoid this.

Comment: I didn't catch that it was per collection. I had several test databases with several collections each. Ouch!